# Solving logarithms using variables

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, logarithm

LogQ= a+bLogP+cLogI+dLogPm

b= -2.174
c= 0.461
d= 1.909

Determine price elasticity of demand, income elasticity, and cross price elasticity

Comment: I've tried utilizing the following computations: LogQ = PI(with a as the exponent)Pm(with -2.174 as the exponent), also LogQ = Log (PIPm)+ 4.544

Comment: Looks like a question on how to interpret the coefficients. Is it useful to `exp` both sides?

Comment: That I am unsure of. I can't determine if it would be better to use the independent variables instead of the actual values.

Comment: This question seems specialized to economics.  To achieve wider understanding of what you are asking, please tell your audience what $Q$, $P$, $I$, and $P_m$ mean and how they are supposed to be related to these elasticities.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_(economics)

This isn't really a statistics question, more just a straightforward application of the definitions of demand, income and cross-price elasticity.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, more like a comment. In future, please discriminate between them.